# Is there a fault / problem in the Stack Overflow login feature or did I just do something wrong?

Tags: bug, login

Just now I tried to log in to Stack Overflow, and I received an error message saying that the password was wrong.
It then told me to *"try again"*, so I logged in again (using the exact same password) and it sent me off to a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) page.

After I completed the CAPTCHA (I did get it correct), it told me to try logging in again, so once again I logged in (with the exact same email and password), and to my amazement the page told me that something went wrong.

Obviously I found it (incredibly) hard to believe that *something went wrong on **Stack Overflow*** so I (in the spirit of Windows users) just closed my browser in the hopes that the problem would go away after a quick restart.
After I went back to the login page and logged in SO was working perfectly fine.

- What went wrong?
- Is it my fault (or did something go wrong on my computer) or is there a problem at SO?
- How can I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: caps lock ? switch to another language's on keyboard ?

Comment: If the problem stops when you restart the PC, the problem was on your end. CAPSLOCK / keyboard language are quite possible to have been the problem.

Comment: @Walfrat No it wasn't I don't bother to write in languages other than English (I only have the en-GB language installed) also I don't enable caps lock I just use shift.

Comment: @Cerbrus I did not restart the PC, I restarted the browser.

Comment: Also, can someone explain the down vote?

Comment: My comment still applies. If doong something on your end fixes the issue, the issue was probably on your end.

Comment: don't get annoyrd on downvotes on meta, their differ from regular site, it probably means that he thinked it was on your side.